# Grid Layout elements to match parent size

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to make text input components match the size of the screen.
For example this is how I want it to look like. 
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMcAv.jpg)

however, if the size of the the screen is bigger this is what I get. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAseR.jpg)

So, here's my code.

```
 <GridLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/TopBarLayout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/BottomBarLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/PatientLayout"
    android:rowCount="6"
    android:columnCount="1">
    <EditText
        style="@style/Editor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/PatientFirstNameEditText"
        android:hint="@string/FirstNameHint"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    <EditText
        style="@style/Editor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/PatientLastNameEditText"
        android:hint="@string/LastNameHint"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    <EditText
        style="@style/Editor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/PatientMiddleNameEditText"
        android:hint="@string/MiddleNameHint"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TopBarLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:background="#e8e8f5"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <EditText
            android:inputType="date"
            style="@style/Editor"
            android:id="@+id/DateOfBirthEditText"
            android:layout_weight="90"
            android:layout_width="0dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/calendar"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:id="@+id/ShowDatePickerButton"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5.0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        style="@style/Editor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/PatientSocialSecurityNumberEditText"
        android:hint="@string/SocialSecurityNumberHint"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/TopBarLayout"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <RadioButton
            android:text="@string/Male"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/PatientMaleRadioButton"
            android:checked="true" />
        <RadioButton
            android:text="@string/Female"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/PatientFemaleRadioButton" />
    </RadioGroup>
</GridLayout>
```

I have set margins so that it would match 5inch screen.
I want components to be adaptable to the size of the screen. so for example if the screen is small, text should be proportionally smaller as well.
I want to get the same result from gridlayout as from the grid panel from C# winform. 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using multiple XML files to support different screen sizes?

Comment: And why are you using grid layout to display single column? Why dont you go for LinearLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since everything you want to build is in one column of your grid, you can use a vertical linear layout on the outside and inner EditTexts and a horizontal linear layout for the two radio buttons. You can use `android:layout_weight` to set the elements to be a percentage of the page. You can also play with `android:layout_margin` to change their margins more specifically, there is also marginTop/Bottom/Right etc. Hope this helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#000000 ">


   <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="0.1"
       android:id="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_margin="20dp"
       android:background="#ffffff "
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

   <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="0.1"
       android:id="@+id/editText2"
       android:layout_margin="20dp"
       android:background="#ffffff "
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

   <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="0.1"
       android:id="@+id/editText3"
       android:layout_margin="20dp"
       android:background="#ffffff "
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

   <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="0.1"
       android:id="@+id/editText4"
       android:layout_margin="20dp"
       android:background="#ffffff "
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

   <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="0.1"
       android:id="@+id/editText5"
       android:layout_margin="20dp"
       android:background="#ffffff "
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="0.1"
       android:background="#123123 "
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

       <RadioButton
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight=".5"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Option 1"
           android:id="@+id/radioButton" />
       <RadioButton
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight=".5"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Option 2"
           android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="0.1"
       android:text="New Button"
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but, how can I do the same with the font size?

Comment: You're gonna wanna look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAppearance) 
I've never had a problem with it so I've never actually used this but it looks right

Comment: Or use this
`android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"`